# "If you want, I can do this "vs "I can do this, if you want" which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I am not sure which one of the two forms is correct:
"If you want, I can do this"
vs 
"I can do this, if you want"

Do the above sentences have different meaning? even slightly?

Other example:

"I am going to pick blue if its okay with you" vs "If its okay with you I am going to pick blue"

Comment: Both are correct, for both. It would be rash to deny *any* difference in meaning, but it seems pretty negligible in these instances.

Comment: Both work - they have different emphasis. Starting with the decision (I am going...) or main clause emphasizes the outcome, while starting with "if" stresses on the condition. 
Consider replacing "if" with `as long as` for another feel to the condition.

Comment: Nevertheless, the question is incorrect, because it presupposes that, of two variants of an English sentence, only one can be correct. This is total nonsense, and no part of English grammar.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, the word "can" means that you have the  *ability* to "do this." Instead of using the word "can" I think you should use the word "will."  With that in mind, I think your two forms should be:

"If you want, I will do this"

VS

"I will do this, if you want."

Because we read from left to right, the emphasis will more naturally fall on the first part of the phrase.

So the answer to your question depends on what you want to emphasize.

If you want to emphasize the fact that you are empathetic and wish to be helpful then the first form should be used.

If you want to emphasize the fact that you are capable and willing to do something then the second form should be used.

Answer (score 0):

"I can do this if you want" most directly represents the sense, and the version with "if you want" in initial position is produced by an optional movement rule that brings "if you want" to the front.  One can see this by considering the interpretation of "If you want, I think I can do this", where it is evident that my thinking something isn't really contingent on you wanting something.  The "if you want (me to ...)" must have been preposed from its original position in construction with "(then) I ... do this".  (This is a variation of an argument cited by George Lakoff in *Linguistics and Natural Logic*.)